# Firebase storage fetching image fails randomly

Tags: firebase, gatsby

This is more of a bug report than a question, but I hope someone from Firebase could shed some light here.

I have a Gatsby website with a script in gatsby-node.js that fetches Firestore records. This part works fine.

Each record has an image_url field with a url to an image hosted on Firebase Storage, like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-app.appspot.com/o/users%xxx%2Fimages%2F1632369732349.jpg?alt=media&token=599dec9f-936b-4529-815a-965a1dc70047`

The script iterates over every meal and downloads the image so it can be converted to a GatsbyImage.

My script is:

```js
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  getCache,
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === "Restaurants") {
    const mealsWithImages = node.meals.map(async (meal, index) => {
      if (meal.image_url) {
        let remoteImageNode;
        let retries = 0; // initialize counter for image download retries
        while (retries < 11) {
          try {
            if(retries > 0){
              console.log("Try No.", retries, meal)
            }
            remoteImageNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
              url: meal.image_url,
              parentNodeId: node.id,
              createNode,
              createNodeId,
              getCache,
            });
            if(retries > 0){
              console.log("Successfully downloaded image on retry No.", retries)
            }
            break; // break out of the loop if successful
          } catch (error) {
            console.log({error: "FAILED TO GET IMAGE", image_url: meal.image_url, retries});
            retries++;
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // wait for 5 seconds before retrying
          }
        }

        if (remoteImageNode) {
          // ...
        }
      }
    });

    // ...
  }
};
```

Half the times I run this script during `gatsby build`, it works and fetches all the images and builds the template pages correctly. However, it **randomly** fails to fetch images, and when it does, it's different images that it fails to fetch.
As you can see I added a failsafe loop to retry fetching thinking it may be a connection error.

Unfortunately, when it fails to get an image, the loop works well, but it's not getting the image on retries. It keeps failing.

More interestingly, I print out in console log the image path, and as it goes through the loop, I coped the image link that is failing and opened it in a browser and it shows the image while it's failing the loop.

The error message for the failed fetch is something like this:

```
{
  error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/.../.cache/caches/gatsby-source-filesystem/tmp-edf6ab08b948f29edf5ff146da2e3e17.jpg' ->
'/Users/.../.cache/caches/gatsby-source-filesystem/.../users-....jpg'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'rename',
    path: '/Users/.../.cache/caches/gatsby-source-filesystem/tmp-edf6ab08b948f29edf5ff146da2e3e17.jpg',
    dest: '/Users/.../.cache/caches/gatsby-source-filesystem/.../users-....jpg'
  }
}
```